# How to add tuple to List and avoid java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: list, scala, scala-collections

When I try to add an object of type (Int, String) to a List I receive below exception :

```
var data = List((10, "test1"))                    
data.add((11, "here"))  

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:131)
java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:91)
```

How can I add this tuple (11, "here") to the List 'data' ?

Why am I receiving this exception ?

Comment: Are you using java lists? Because, this code won't compile otherwise (at least, on scala 2.8-2.10). How does List is defined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` imported, and you're trying to use the Java mutable `add` operation on a Scala immutable list.

It won't work!

Maybe you just want to

```
var data = List((1, "one"))
data = (2, "two") :: data
```

Comment: this prepends tuple to data. What is they syntax for appending.
data = data :: (2, "two") gives error

Comment: @Haider - You can use `data = data :+ ((2, "two"))`, but you shouldn't use a `List` for that.  Appends on lists are slow.  If you're building a list, prepend and then reverse the whole thing at the end (or use a `List.newBuilder` with `+=` mutably, and then generate the immutable `List` at the end with `result`).